Microsoft Graph API - Advanced Query / Query String Search "Choice Column"
Searching for "Choice Columns" on site pages at sharepoint with the advanced query is impossible I assume with the "advanced query" part
However searching for metadata columns is possible but doing the same with the choice columns is not possible, is there any way to do it?
working example (metadata column):
metadata_language:DE
non-working example (choice column):
choice_language:DE

Could you please share the whole URL of the endpoint? Only to be clear where do you perform searching

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query

still I haven't found something @RaytheonXie-MSFT . I have seen some articles where it may be possible to do it with the $filter option but that is not the thing I want unfortunately, I want to do it via the query which is possible for the metadata columns but not for the choice ones. (It may be possible but I still have not found out how, don't take my 'not possible' in the negative way )
